# How to change pickupexten on asterisk 11

Tags: linux, freebsd, asterisk

I'm looking for a way to change ‍pickupexten in Asterisk 11. Is there a way?

The `features.conf:`

```
pickupexten = *8
pickupgroup=1
pickupsound = beep
pickupfailsound = beeperr
```

I want to change *8 with any number. But when I changed it, It doesn't work.(I restarted asterisk after the changes) I checked the source I think the *8 is hard code and it can't change so what is the solution?

Thank you for giving a solution other than changing the Asterisk version because for some reason I must use this version of Asterisk.

Thank you all again

Comment: The thing is, it's `pickupexten` indeed. So this "doesn't work" of yours is a vague diagnostics example and really doesn't explain anything.

Comment: P.S And "it works". Just checked.

Comment: I have a huge dialplan and config files. I don't know which part can help to explain the problem. With *8 I can use pickup feature but if i want to change it with another number that number doesn't work.